# Splitting SQL query returned records into an array

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Hey all I am wanting to split my returned query records into a "paging" type of thing so therefore I am wanting to display the first 51 records and then add the rest into an array to fetch later when the user wants to move to another page.

I can display the first 51 results just fine on the page but I am having trouble with finding out a way to divide the rest of the records by 51.

My code so far:

```
var arrayHTML       = [];

for(var key in data){
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (totalX >= 51) {
            //Start putting the results into an array. 51 results per array
        }else if (x > 1) {
            x = 0;
            _userName = data[key].fname + ' ' + data[key].lname;

            populateCards(_userName, 
                          data[key].email, 
                          data[key].img, 
                          data[key].school, 
                          data[key].userID, 
                          true,
                          data[key].encoded);
        } else {
            _userName = data[key].fname + ' ' + data[key].lname;

            populateCards(_userName, 
                          data[key].email, 
                          data[key].img, 
                          data[key].school, 
                          data[key].userID, 
                          false, 
                          data[key].encoded);
            x++;
        }

        totalRowCnt = data[key].totalRows;
        _tmpMath = Math.round(totalRowCnt / totalNum);
        total++;
        totalX++;

        console.log('totalX: ' + totalX)
    }
}
```

After it hits the 51 it goes into the **if (totalX >= 51) {** and this is where I am trying to figure out how to go about splitting the rest up into 51 per array slot.

The code above is looping until it gets to every **3rd record** and then placing an **< br/>** after that so it has one row of 3 records then it just keeps doing that until it reaches record 51. **So 17 rows of 3 records per row.** The **true** is telling the function to put the **< br/>** on the end while the **false** is telling the function not to put the **< br/>** on yet.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Code Below:

Add this function to your code:

```
// this is a simple pager function that return part of the array you want
//  so you can easily loop over it
// @param page you want
// @param how many values you want
// @return the sliced array with the parts you want
//     (this will return an empty array if your page is out of bound
//       e.g. when you array only contains less than 51 and you tell it you want page 2)
array_pager = function ( array, page, show ) {
   var start = (page -1) * show; // this sets the offset
   return array.slice( start, start + show);
}
```

And you could use this function like this:

```
// assuming the array's name is data
var this_page = array_pager( data, 1, 51); // get this_page 1, with 51 values

// then you can safely loop over it
for(var key in this_page) {
  _userName = this_page[key].fname + ' ' + this_page[key].lname;

  populateCards(_userName, 
                this_page[key].email, 
                this_page[key].img, 
                this_page[key].school, 
                this_page[key].userID, 
                false, 
                this_page[key].encoded);
}

// for page 2: array_pager( data, 2, 51) ... 
// 10 per page: array_pager( data, 1, 10) ... I think you get it now
```